# Insert after trigger not working properly want to Update table in inset after trriger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, msdn

I have one table and trigger on that which is doing some calculation and updating the column.

I want to update input mode field want to set 0 and 1 day wise in a table.
I write following code that but not working properly.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Convert(datetime, el.M_Edatetime)) AS ROW,
        el.LogId 
    FROM 
        Essl_logdata el 
    INNER JOIN
        Inserted i ON el.EnrollNo = i.EnrollNo 
                   AND el.M_Edatetime = i.M_Edatetime
    WHERE 
        el.EnrollNo = @INS 
        AND Convert(Date, el.M_Edatetime) = Convert(date, @M_datetime)
)
UPDATE Essl_logdata 
SET InOutMode = '0' 
FROM CTE 
WHERE ROW%2 <> 0 AND Essl_logdata.LogId = CTE.LogId;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COnvert(datetime, el.M_Edatetime)) AS ROW,
        el.LogId 
    FROM 
        Essl_logdata el 
    INNER JOIN
        Inserted i ON el.EnrollNo = i.EnrollNo 
                   AND el.M_Edatetime = i.M_Edatetime 
    WHERE
        el.EnrollNo = @INS 
        AND Convert(Date, el.M_Edatetime) = Convert(date, @M_datetime)
)
UPDATE Essl_logdata 
SET InOutMode = '1' 
FROM CTE 
WHERE ROW%2 = 0 AND Essl_logdata.LogId = CTE.LogId;
```

Expected result is as follow.

[image]

The current query in trigger show result like this.

[image: data in inoutmode should 0 or 1 day wise and EnrollNo wise]

Comment: I can't see how the two images differ. It's also unclear why the "Month" column is highlighted when the question seems to be focussed on the "InOutMode" column. Some sample data and expected results, *as text*, would remarkably improve this question.

Comment: Sorry  Inoutmode column is important i want to update that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COnvert(date,M_Edatetime),EnrollNo ORDER BY COnvert(datetime,M_Edatetime))AS ROW,Logid,M_Edatetime,EnrollNo FROM Essl_logdata  group by M_Edatetime,Logid,EnrollNo
        )           
        Update Essl_logdata set InOutMode = '1' FROM CTE WHERE ROW%2 = 0 and Essl_logdata.LogId = CTE.LogId;

WITH CTE AS
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COnvert(date,M_Edatetime),EnrollNo ORDER BY COnvert(datetime,M_Edatetime))AS ROW,Logid,M_Edatetime,EnrollNo FROM Essl_logdata  group by M_Edatetime,Logid,EnrollNo
        )       
        Update Essl_logdata set InOutMode = '0' FROM CTE WHERE ROW%2 <> 0 and Essl_logdata.LogId = CTE.LogId;
```

I find  this solution to workaround